# SSAS : Filter Cube

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, analysisservices, multidimensional-cube

I have dimension and fact table. The dimension is PATIENTDBOID meanwhile the fact table is Total_Admissions.
Now, I want to filter for Patient that Admission >1

[image]

Can someone help me how. ?

Comment: Where you are trying to Achieve ? SSMS or Any other Application like PowerBI?
You are using Tabular/Multi Dimension cube ?

Comment: I am using SSAS. and I confuse to do filter using the SSAS application

Comment: I Know you are using SSAS. Which Model you are using Tabular/Multi Dimension Cube ? MDX or DAX ?

Comment: Multidimensional,MDX

Comment: You can use filter. Refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/filter-mdx?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use `Filter` Function to Apply filter on Measures with Logical Expression.

Since I don't know Exact Dimension Name, You can try something like below.

`0` - Represents COLUMNS

`1` - Represents Rows

```
SELECT [Measures].[Total_Admissions] ON 0,

FILTER(
  [Patient].[Patient].[PatientDBOID].MEMBERS
, [Measures].[Total_Admissions]>1)
ON 1

FROM [Cube Name]
```

Comment: it is possible I put it in the calculation in the SSAS ? can u show how?

Comment: Hi its me again, I created the filter in the calculation into Cube SSAS but it return null. can u tell me why, or there are other option to do the filter?